# Mkdir() permission denied C/linux programming

Tags: c, linux, permissions, mkdir

when I execute this code, I get the error `Couldn't create backup sub-directory: Permission denied` but I can't understand why since I give full permisions and I'm using a admin account on ubuntu.

```
umask(0777);
int folder_date_status = mkdir(filepath_W, 0777);

if(folder_date_status == -1){
    perror("Couldn't create backup sub-directory");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ - you will win time by taking some hours to read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An admin account doesn't run with full privileges by default. This is so that programs you run don't unexpectedly act as privileged users (ie. you must explicitly give permission).

To give permission to the program to create a sub-directory in a directory which requires privileged access, try using `sudo`.

If the program name is called `myprogram`, try running:

```
sudo ./myprogram
```

Then type your password if it is requested.

Note that super-user access should only be required if it is trying to make a subdirectory in a write-restricted directory (eg. restricted directory owned by root, or another user). Also ensure that the parent directory exists (otherwise it could also throw an error).

Comment: That solved half of my problem because I put the mask with full permissions (0777) when I try to open the new created folder, I have the error "no permissions to see folder's content"...

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify your filepath_w? Do you have permissio to read, write and execute on it? I suggest you to use a absolute pathname and point it to the tmp dir, something like this:

filepath_w = "/tmp/directory"